# how to get value from locked variable in release pipeline power shell script task

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

Here I want to access `ICSPAdminPassword` locked value in the PowerShell script.
I wanted to create database user in pipepline so query require adminpassword and adminpassword
is locked and it apear blank.

I have tried envirnment variable.

Powershell script task
[image]

pipeline locked variable
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the PowerShell task, you need to set an Environment variable, where the name is the name of the environment variable, and the value is the reference to the pipeline variable.  For example:

[image: EnvironmentVariable]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the configuration of the environment variable?